# How to make my application run fast with facebook and linkedin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, performance, rest, linkedin-api

Please bear with me while I provide a short background:

1. My application retrieves user data from Facebook and LinkeIn.
2. Both have very strict terms of use. Specifically, **they do not
   allow    to save user data on my application** (well, kind-of.
   Facebook allows    caching. Linked does not allow even caching).
3. The naive solution is to call Facebook/LinkedIn whenever I need the 
   data from them. The problem is that this becomes too slow if I need
   lots of data (e.g. profiles of 100 users). Batch calls make things
   better, but they have limits and I'm not sure this approach can
   scale.

**So the question is how to make my application run fast while using data from Facebook/LinkedIn?**

If you can share from your experience, or have an example for a site that uses lots of data from Facebook/LinkedIn I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you talk about making your application "fast", please note "fast" can mean either "high throughput" or "low latency", and there is a big difference between the two. It would be good to set performance goals for both latency (how quickly each individual user should be served) and throughput (how many users you should be able to serve per unit time).

If getting data from FB/LinkedIn is a bottleneck for *throughput*,

1. Use batched requests.
2. If the same data can be used repeatedly, cache as much of it as you can and for as long as you can.
3. Make sure your application is able to issue many requests in parallel. Since sending a query over the network is a high-latency operation, you can gain a LOT of throughput this way.

If getting data from FB/LinkedIn is a bottleneck for *latency*,

1. Again, cache as much data as you can locally.
2. If it is possible to "guess" which data will be needed soon, pre-fetch it. (For example: if your user has to fill out a big form and then submit, but there is a critical field in that form which identifies the data you will need, you could use AJAX to make the page send that field back as soon as it is filled in, rather than waiting for the whole form to be submitted!)
3. If you need multiple pieces of data to service a single user, DON'T fetch them with multiple sequential requests -- either use a batched request, or multiple parallel requests (perhaps both).
4. When it is necessary to make the user wait, "distract" them -- do whatever you can to make the wait *seem* shorter.
5. If there are certain parts of a page which can be rendered without FB/LinkedIn data, send those parts back first, and use AJAX calls to fill in the other parts when the data is ready.

If you absolutely must have data XYZ from FB/LinkedIn to serve a user, and the latency of a single API request is N seconds, and your target maximum time to serve each user is < N seconds, the only possible way you can reach your goal is by prefetching data. Maybe when you see the very first page request come in for a user (say for the home page), you can start loading all the data which will be needed for that user into the cache (if it's not already there).

Whatever you do, I recommend that you encapsulate your FB/LinkedIn data access code inside a "data access layer". Caching should happen strictly *inside* the data access layer -- the application code doesn't need to know about the cache. Whether you use batched calls or not, and whether you issue multiple calls in parallel is also an implementation details which should be kept strictly inside the data access layer.

Comment: What is your latency goal? Have you measured the latency of a single call to the LinkedIn API?

Comment: Yes (well, for facebook, not linkedin). I got values up to 4 seconds for batch calls. This is about as high as I can afford...

Comment: Reading your question again, it seems that your problem may be that latency is too high when you need to make *many calls* to get a lot of data from FB/LinkedIn. If this is so, and a single batch call is not enough, you can simply issue multiple batched calls in parallel. If the latency of a single call is acceptable, the latency of multiple parallel calls will be too.

Comment: Is it possible for you to "predict" what data will be needed?

Comment: In some cases yes. But still there is a major use case, where the user signs into the service for the first time, where I immediately need to get lots of information on his behalf. I can't do that up front, since I need the user's token for that.

Comment: In that case, the user will have to wait for at least a single FB/LinkedIn API call to complete. It's fundamentally impossible to do better. If the problem is that you need "lots" of data, can you start providing at least some service (with partial data) after the first batched call completes, and continue loading the rest of the data "in the background"?

Comment: What I need to do is sort the list of profiles I show to the user, based on information that is found in those profiles, so unless I change the sorting after I start displaying, I can't do that before I have all the data.

Comment: In that case, the absolute best you can for latency is the latency of a single API call. Use enough parallel batched calls that you can download *all* the needed data in parallel, and optimize the code which processes the downloaded data, so it is not a bottleneck. Also consider loading the "framework" of the page first, and then filling in the list of profiles asynchronously (using AJAX). (You can use a funky little spinner or other animation until the profiles load.)

Answer (score 3):

> Specifically, they do not allow to save user data on my application (well, kind-of. Facebook allows caching. **Linked does not allow even caching**).

That’s not true … http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use:

> B. Store Content Only As Allowed, 3. Cache for Performance:
>
> To improve the member experience, you may cache LinkedIn Content, but you must not do so for more than 24 hours from your original request. This limited permission to cache is for performance reasons only.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Apparently, they changed the terms of use a week ago: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/updates-our-linkedin-developer-terms-service. However, even with caching I have a latency problem, since the user has to wait while I fetch the data for the first time.